# Django form field doesn't appear on the template

Tags: django, forms, templates, render

I try to use Django forms but I have problems displaying all the fields on my Template.

I have created a form in the form.py file as:

```
class UploadCSVForm(forms.Form):

     title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Please type here", required=True)
     csv_load = forms.FileField()
```

In my corresponding view I import the form as:

```
from myproject.myapp.forms import UploadCSVForm
```

and then in the specific view function I render the form as;

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    ....
    ....
    form = UploadCSVForm()
    ctx['form'] = form
    return render_to_response(template, RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

Last in my template I call the form as:

```
<form id="file-uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url "layer" %}">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
           {{ field.errors }}
           {{ field.help_text }}
           {{ field }}
       {% endfor %}

      <button type="submit" id="upload-button" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

I only get to see the csv_load but not the title.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you see both fields if you use `{{ form }}` instead of looping through the fields?

Comment: Nope. I see only the second one.

Comment: Is that your actual code? The form you have posted works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was blind. I have restarted the localserver but the process was not ended. I had to kill it (kill -9 PID) and after starting the localserver again everything worked fine.